# How to save HLS stream with adaptive bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, hls

I have been trying to monitor the impact of network on HLS stream. I have a HLS stream with different bitrate (360/720/1080) and I would like to save video as played in player with adaptive bitrate and corrupted pixels. I have tried some tools, but they are saving it in best bitrate.

Basically, I would like to save HLS stream as user would see it in their player.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.